# file uploading in asp.Net MVC3

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor

I'm trying to implement a file upload system and I don't really get what to do.

I'm looking for the easiest way to do it. After long researches, I've found those explanations.

[forums.asp.net/t/1678157.aspx/2/10](http://forums.asp.net/t/1678157.aspx/2/10)

So, here is the things I've done inside the view :

```
 @Code
     Dim fileName As String = ""
     If (IsPost) Then
         Dim uploadedFile = Request.Files(0)
         fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName)
         fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/" + fileName)
         uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath)
     End If
 End Code

 <form action="" method="post">
    @FileUpload.GetHtml(
         initialNumberOfFiles := 1,
         allowMoreFilesToBeAdded := False,
         includeFormTag := True,
         uploadText := "Upload")
 </form>
```

Problem : GetHtml is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload'
What can I do to fix this? Is it the good way to handle file uploads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem can be, because you forgot the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form post.

Then maybe your Upload plugin is not installed correctly. 
I assume your are using WebMatrix, so [this article](http://evonet.com.au/webmatrix-uploading-images-with-the-fileupload-helper/) can be of help

Comment: I'm using VS2010... Does it change smth? There was a plugin to install? I hadn't seen it... That might be the problem I've had the whole day

Comment: I never used it, but looking at the turorial it seems that something must be installed (maybe for non VS2010 guys).

Comment: I installed this : http://nuget.org/packages/microsoft-web-helpers but it did not help that much. The error about "@FileUpload.GetHtml" changed. Now, it tells me that FileUpload is not declared and might be not accessible due to protection level.

Comment: with the enctype and the correct using it should work. Sorry but I can't be of more help than this

Answer (score 1):

Scott Hanselman has a great article on implementing this [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx)

The code is in C# but it should get you started

Comment: Thx for this article. It doesn't matter if it's in C#, I'm used to converters now^^

Comment: I got a problem with this article. Impossible to convert a 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase' into 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile'. I already had this problem with a howto used before.